# Keep % format of float values

Tags: python, pandas

How do you keep your `float` in the % format?

```
df['growth_rate'] = df['growth_rate'].replace('%', '', regex=True).astype(float, errors='ignore')/100
```

After changing the column from str to floats, how do you change the format from `0.2345` to `23.45%`? For example, after the column type was converted to `float`, it would be like this:

```
    growth_rate    growth_rate2    growth_rate3
0        0.2345          0.4253          0.3643
1        0.1473             NaN          0.1735
2           NaN          0.6936          0.5925
3        0.2500          0.2746             NaN
```

How do you make it look like this while still keeping the type in `float`:

```
    growth_rate    growth_rate2    growth_rate3
0        23.45%          42.53%          36.43%
1        14.73%             NaN          17.35%
2           NaN          69.36%          59.25%
3        25.00%          27.46%             NaN
# NaN is fine, as long as it can be performed in some calculation later on
```

**Update:** I'm just looking for a simple one-line code if possible. Thanks for your input.

Comment: What does "change the format" mean? You want to undo the conversion from string to float?

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed some sample values from this column before your did this operation and what your desired output would be.

Comment: @Aran-Fey I want to keep the type as `floats` but having the cells displayed in `xx.xx%` format. Is it even doable?

Comment: I don't think you can do that, but I'm not a pandas buff.

Comment: @Aran-Fey Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can take your column and send it through `to_string`:

```
output = df.to_string(formatters={'growth_rate': '{:,.2%}'.format})
print(output)

 growth_rate
0      23.45%
1      14.73%
2        nan%
3      25.00%
```

This doesn't change your data frame (which is still in `float`):

```
In [ 7]: df
Out[ 7]: 
   growth_rate
0       0.2345
1       0.1473
2          NaN
3       0.2500
```

but generates a string representation of the `growth_rate` column you can print.

To output all the columns, pass a list of formatters as long as the number of columns:

```
df['growth_rate2'] = [0.1,0.04,0.876,np.nan]
output = df.to_string(formatters=['{:,.2%}'.format]*2)
```

To output only particular columns in your special format, use a dictionary with the column names as the keys:

```
df['growth_rate3'] = [0.071,0.02,0.,0.66]
df.to_string(formatters={'growth_rate': '{:,.2%}'.format,
                         'growth_rate3': '{:,.2%}'.format})
```

Comment: Thanks. But the problem is I want to keep them as `float` for calculation purposes

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you want to do: this doesn't change the values, it just generates a string of output with the values formatted in percentages.

Comment: I think your method does work. There's one thing, what if I just want to do this to several columns in the file? I tried `output = df.to_string(formatters={['growth_rate', 'growth_rate2', 'growth_rate3']: '{:,.2%}'.format})`. And I got an error: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

Comment: Thanks for the update. When I ran `df.to_string(formatters=['{:,.2%}'.format]*2)`, I got an error of `list index out of range`.

Comment: You have to replace `*2` with `*n` where `n` is the number of columns you have. In your case, `*3` apparently.

Comment: I tried and it still returned me the same error. Here's what I did, `df[['growth_rate', 'growth_rate2', 'growth_rate3']] = df.to_string(formatters=['{:,.2%}'.format]*3)`. I can't figure it out what goes wrong here though.

Comment: `df.to_string` returns a `str` (string) object. You probably don't want to try to assign your dataframe to that string. Just `print` it.

Comment: Yes, it seems that it's the only method left. Thanks for your method.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one...

```
import math
import pandas as pd

def get_percentage(value: float):
    """ This function converts the floating-point integer into float
    type percentage string.
    :param value: A floating point integer.
    :return string: Percentage representation of the input value with % symbol at the end.
    """
    if math.isnan(value):
        return "NaN"
    else:
        return "{}%".format(round(value * 100,2))

# Create  a data frame
data = {'Growth_Rate1': [0.2345,0.1473,math.nan,0.2500],
            'Growth_Rate2': [0.4252,math.nan,0.6936,0.2746],
            'Growth_Rate3': [0.3643,0.1735,0.5925,math.nan],
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Get the shape of the data frame
rows, cols = df.shape

# Display the data frame
print(df)

# Display the data frame with formatted values
print("---"*20)
print("\t".join(df.columns))
for row in range(rows):
    for col in range(cols):
        print(get_percentage(df.loc[row][col]), end="\t\t")
    print()
print("---"*20)
```

**Output:**

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------

       Growth_Rate1  Growth_Rate2  Growth_Rate3
0        0.2345        0.4252        0.3643
1        0.1473           NaN        0.1735
2           NaN        0.6936        0.5925
3        0.2500        0.2746           NaN
----------------------------------------------------------------------

Growth_Rate1    Growth_Rate2    Growth_Rate3
   23.45%          42.52%          36.43%       
   14.73%             NaN          17.35%       
      NaN          69.36%          59.25%       
   25.00%          27.46%             NaN       
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Please let me know whether it worked or not.

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate your help and method. But I was just looking for some simple one-line code rather than a function and for loop. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Karma You can achieve the same by using 2 more approaches, one is the **to_string()** function and another one is by storing the _%_ representation of the same in a separate column of the DataFrame (Not Recommended), this will unnecessarily increase the size of your DataFrame, to avoid this you can utilize an external storage resource such as a CSV file.

Comment: Thanks. I actually did the latter one -- by creating other columns that show the percentage in the string format because I still need the float columns for calculation purposes. Thanks for your help again!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe using [pandas style](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html#Finer-Control:-Display-Values)?

```
df.style.format("{:.2%}")
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried it using `df[['growth_rate', 'growth_rate2', 'growth_rate3']] = df.style.format("{:.2%}")`, but now all the cells return `<pandas.io.formats.style.Styler object at 0x10dee3278>`. What did I do wrong here? Thanks.

Comment: the styler has a lot of fancy things that, apparently, led the designers to specialize it for HTML output. It should work just fine in a Jupyter Notebook (you might have to use IPython.display.HTML), otherwise I had to call `.render()` to convert it to HTML which I then visualized in a browser. I couldn't get this to display in a plain text terminal.

Comment: I use PyCharm IDE and save all the columns, comprised of strings and floats, to a csv file. But the columns I used this `pandas style format` method all become `pandas.io.formats.style.Styler object at xxxxx`

Comment: `pandas.io.formats.style.Styler` is an object that, as far as I can tell, exists solely to control the formatting of a DataFrame when producing HTML output. It can't (and shouldn't) affect the actual data in your dataframe (if you want that, use one of the many `to_string` answers already given), it _only_ affects display, and unfortunately in this case, is _only_ usable with an HTML viewer. You shouldn't be assigning the resulting value to your dataframe, it's not meant to modify the underlying data, just present it in a specific way.

Comment: If you want to save to a CSV file and want that file to have the `%` formatting, then just use the `to_string` answer already given to format the floats as desired before saving. You seem to want a perfect solution that makes floats always get displayed in `%` format without actually being stored that way, and that almost certainly doesn't exist. You can also store the `%` formatted version of the float in a second column so that you're not losing your actual float values in the process

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to achieve. Keeping the floats while displaying them in `%` format. I thought they would operate the same way in Python regardless of decimal or percentage when it comes to calculation. But it seems that I might have to create other columns that show the `%` in string as you suggested. Thanks for the explanation.