# Convert string to float and keep % format

Tags: python, pandas

I initially had the columns below in `string`, and I converted them into `float` for some calculation purposes.

```
  Growth1               Growth2
4,365.46%               124.48%
   45.29%       2.222222222222%  
  251.48%      23.999999999999%

df[['Growth1', 'Growth2']] = df[['Growth1', 'Growth2']].replace('%|,', '', regex=True).astype(float, errors='ignore')/100

  Growth1               Growth2
  43.6546                1.2448
   0.4529      0.02222222222222  
   2.5148      0.23999999999999
```

However, they are in decimal format and I want them to show in % format. But I can't just add `{:,.2%}'.format` after a line like:

```
df[['Growth1', 'Growth2']] = df[['Growth1', 'Growth2']].replace('%|,', '', regex=True).astype(float, errors='ignore')/100(formatters=[{:,.2%}'.format])
```

Is there any way that you can do to keep the `float` in `% format` and round it to the 2 decimal places with the least amount of code (like 1 or 2 lines)? Thank you.

Desired output:

```
  Growth1     Growth2
4,365.46%     124.48%
   45.29%       2.22%  
  251.48%      24.00%    # or 23.99%, no big deal
```

Comment: How is this different from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49564874/keep-format-of-float-values)?

Comment: I've flagged this as a duplicate and posted an answer to your original question. I think that'll be what you're looking for. @pault thanks for dup link

Comment: @pault I thought I didn't clarify my concern in my previous question. So I asked another modified question.

Comment: @Karma it's better practice to update/edit your previous question with new information

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the parameter you use for `format` is not correct. It should be `{:,.2f}`, and % outside:

Example:

```
>>> "{:,.2f}%".format(4365.46)
'4,365.46%'
```

Comment: Thanks. So if I want to convert the whole column to this format instead of a single value, I used `df['Growth1'] = "{:,.2f}%".format(df['Growth1'])`. But I got the error of `unsupported format string passed to Series.__format__`

Answer (score 1):

```
df['Growth1'] = pd.Series(['{0:.2f}%'.format(val * 100) for val in df['Growth1']], index = df.index)
```

The same for "Growth2" column.

Note: if you want to keep the original column, just name the new one something other than "Growth1"

Comment: Thank you for providing your method. I tried it, the cells definitely converted to the % format as I asked. But the type also converted to `str`, whereas I wanted them to stay in `float`.

Comment: A float is a numeric type, you can't "format a float". You can round it, but you can't add a "%" character to a float.
Keep your dataframe column type float and just send a formated version of it to the print function whenever you need to.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Yes, it might be the only way then. Thanks.

Comment: Happy it helped. Just please if your issue was solved, then accept an answer (this or another one which you found most helpful), so that people can see this issue was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe using [pandas style](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html#Finer-Control:-Display-Values)?

```
df.style.format("{:.2%}")
```

When you display the returned object from this call, like you normally would a dataframe, it'll have your columns formatted in the manner you've requested.